Is " Build Project" a compiler in Eclipse?
Im just a beginner in Eclipse for C/C++. Just wanna know the purpose of "Build Project".
The tutorial from a youtube channel shows to click on build project before running. The video doest say why this step was done before running.

Not eclipse specific: Computer hardware doesn't understand programing languages, it uses a machine language. C and C++ are generally implemented as compiled languages. The pieces of a program are translated into machine code pieces (or close to it) by a compiler and combined into a whole by a linker. This process is referred to as building the program. Until this is done successfully, there is nothing that can be run. There are other ways things can be arranged that are used with other languages. (Eclipse is often used with Java, which uses a partially similar, partially different approach.)

More details on above: How does the compilation/linking process work?

Recommendation: Do a few small projects without an IDE. This gives you a better feel for what's going on behind the scenes when you get to larger projects and doing the work by hand no longer makes sense. For the really big stuff you will likely want to use a dedicated build automation tool rather than an IDE, but that is pretty far down the line and you'll have enough experience by then to know when to make the switch.

Anyway, you need to know how builds work by hand so that you stand a chance of troubleshooting the IDE when it screws up or you've misconfigured it.

Side note: Eclipse doesn't have a built-in compiler. Eclipse is a tool that sits on top of a compiler provided by a third party. You likely installed it around the same time, usually slightly before, you installed Eclipse.

Some programs are big enough that they don't fit into a single file and are split up into many files.  Usually the term "project" consists of one or more files that are used to create a program.  Creating the program is also called building.  So the term build project is used to create a program from a bunch of related source files.

No, it's merely the menu item that becomes available if automatic builds are disabled (when enabled, you're always either building or are fully built) to do exactly what it says, based on the project's setup.
